# How to auto-generate settings/options dialog box?

Tags: c++, mfc, settings, auto-generate

Using Visual Studio 2010 C++ with MFC.  The number of configurable settings in my application is slowly creeping up.  I managed to design a settings class where adding a single line will add a setting to the program and support reading/writing that setting to my ini file.  However, I still need to go into my gui editor and edit the options dialog box, moving text boxes around, aligning labels etc. which is kind of a pain.

How would I autogenerate my options dialog box such that I could give it a data structure and it could generate the option interface for me?  It's okay if it's something like a list box.  I'm thinking something like the the Visual Studio properties dialog box which has the look of something that's programmatically generated:

[image: Visual Studio Property Pages]

I'm just trying to get a conceptual overview of what controls would be best and how to piece it together.  Of course if there is a link to a web page discussing this that would be great.

Comment: That's the Winforms PropertyGrid control.  Not available to native code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the `CMFCPropertyGridCtrl` class. It was introduced in one of the MFC updates, but I'm not sure whether or not they come pre-installed with Visual Studio 2010; you may need to install something extra.